# Vocabulary size vs. number of samples

Tags: python, svm, sentiment-analysis

Community,

I am training an SVM for sentiment classification. For the training I use the sentiment140 twitter dataset.

For this process I tried two different approaches:

1. Use only 10 % (160,000 messages) of the Data for training but don't limit the feature size (only 10% for computational reasons)
2. Limit the feature size (vocabulary size) to 12,000 or 20,000 words which allows me to use up to 400,000 twitter messages.

The tokenizer/vectorizer I use uses 1-grams and 2-grams.

Comparing the results, method 1 brings about 80 % accuracy whereas the second method only shows about 79.5 % accuracy.

I am quite unsure about these results and what will perform best for an unlabeled dataset I use for sentiment classification.

The limitation of the vocabulary size would focus the classification on the most common words and on the other hand, could provide more robust learning because of a larger dataset and maybe more accurate classification for the unlabeled dataset?

Having no limitations on the vocab size with a smaller dataset brings the benefit of marginally higher classification accuracy and therefore a better classification for the unlabeled dataset?

I am rather new to this topic and thus not sure about how to decide...

Maybe someone of you can give me an recommendation what would be better?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your purpose? In particular why are you using an SVM? A fine-tuned BERT or RoBERTa model can achieve 85-90% accuracy, see https://paperswithcode.com/sota/text-classification-on-sentiment140  (Be careful with those results, as they report whatever it was after 5 epochs, even though they were clearly over-fitting after 2 to 3 epochs.)

Comment: I compare classical machine learning algorithms with deep learning-based algorithms for sentiment classification. For the ML I use the SVM for the DL I use an LSTM network. My LSTM network reaches about 82.5 % accuracy with a Vocab size of 12,000 words (worse results with smaller or higher vocab size). Therefore the question arises if I should limit the feature size of the SVM even though no accuracy benefits are present.

And thanks for the link! Using a BERT could state useful in the future!